# How can a framework be Java EE compliant?

Tags: jakarta-ee

If I have to develop my own application server, what does it take to say I am Java EE compliant?

For example app servers like GlassFish and WebSphere claim that they are Java EE compliant. What should one do to make sure my application server is Java EE compliant?

Comment: Why would you develop your own JEE app server? This represents a daunting task, and everybody will probably use JEE 45 when you finish your JEE 6 compliant server.

Comment: Vivek, the term "J2EE" refers Java EE 1.2~1.4 versions from the prehistory. Keep yourself up to date and do not use that term to refer the current Java EE 5.0~6.0 versions. They are referenced as "Java EE". Note that the term "JEE" is [strongly discouraged](http://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/JEE) by the spec guys, @JBNizet

Comment: @BalusC - thanks much for pointing out. I get the point.

Answer (score 2):

> What should one do to make sure my application server is a Java EE compliant?

Pass the **Compatibility Test Suite (CTS)**.

From Oracle's [Java EE FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaee-faq-jsp-135209.html#compatibilitytests) on Java EE 6:

> The Java EE Compatibility Test Suite (CTS) is available for the Java
>   EE platform. The Java EE CTS contains thousands of compatibility tests
>   for Java EE 6. The suite tests compatibility by performing specific
>   application functions and checking results. For example, to test the
>   JPA call to persist an entity, an EJB test component makes a call to
>   persist an object and then a call is made to check that the object was
>   persisted.

The full CTS is given to Java EE licencees, but [there are some parts that are public](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10473976/1434089).

Answer (score 0):

The spec is managed by Oracle (it used to be Sun) and you can find information at [Here](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr316/index.html).